# Add pending item to RealmResults with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, realm

I'm managing my UI list with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter. I'd like to add a "pending" item to the collection that will display immediately while simultaneously posting the new item to the server. In case of failure, I will remove it from the display. Similar to a chat feature; I display the chat when they hit send, and if for some reason the post fails I can remove it and alert the user.

The problem is that with a regular RecyclerView adapter, I can just add one item to the end of the collection without an id, and remove it as needed. But since RealmRecyclerViewAdapter uses managed RealmResults, I can't add a new item without an id.

Can someone suggest a way to handle the situation I'm describing with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your data model looks like. It is hard to give concrete advice, but it sounds like all your have ID's, so something like this should work:

1) It must be possible to generate ID's offline. The standard solution for that is GUIDs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier
2) Have a boolean on your model class: "syncedWithServer" or something similar. Then you can render all items not yet synced as "pending".

```
public class ChatEntry extends RealmObject {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  private String entry;
  private boolean syncedWithServer;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I misspoke when I said "I can't add a new item without an id". Technically I can add an id before posting, but I'd need to 1). Create a new chat message with a client generated id 2). Copy it to realm 3). Post to server 4). On success, remove the initial local realm object 5). Copy to realm the new object with the server generated id. I'm guessing this will work, but seems convoluted for something as simple as displaying one extra list item in a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.